# how do you run pytest either from a notebook or command line on databricks?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, databricks

I have created some classes each of which takes a dataframe as a parameter. I have imported pytest and created some fixtures and simple assert methods.

I can call pytest.main([.]) from a notebook and it will execute pytest from the rootdir (databricks/driver).

I have tried passing the notebook path but it says not found.

Ideally, i'd want to execute this from the command line.

How do i configure the rootdir?
There seems to be a disconnect between the spark os and the user workspace area which i'm finding hard to connect.

As a caveat I dont want to use unittest as i pytest can be used successfully in the CI pipleine by outputting junitxml which AzureDevOps can report on.

Answer (score 2):

I've explained the reason why you can't run pytest on Databricks notebooks (unless you export them, and upload them to dbfs as regular .py files, which is not what you want) in the link at the bottom of this post.

However, I have been able to run doctests in Databricks, using the `doctest.run_docstring_examples` method like so:

```py
import doctest

def f(x):
    """
    >>> f(1)
    45
    """
    return x + 1

doctest.run_docstring_examples(f, globals())
```

This will print out:

```
**********************************************************************
File "/local_disk0/tmp/1580942556933-0/PythonShell.py", line 5, in NoName
Failed example:
    f(1)
Expected:
    45
Got:
    2
```

If you also want to raise an exception, take a further look at: https://menziess.github.io/howto/test/code-in-databricks-notebooks/

Answer (score 1):

Taken from Databricks' own repo: https://github.com/databricks/notebook-best-practices/blob/main/notebooks/run_unit_tests.py

```py
# Databricks notebook source
# MAGIC %md Test runner for `pytest`

# COMMAND ----------

!cp ../requirements.txt ~/.
%pip install -r ~/requirements.txt

# COMMAND ----------

# pytest.main runs our tests directly in the notebook environment, providing
# fidelity for Spark and other configuration variables.
#
# A limitation of this approach is that changes to the test will be
# cache by Python's import caching mechanism.
#
# To iterate on tests during development, we restart the Python process 
# and thus clear the import cache to pick up changes.
dbutils.library.restartPython()

import pytest
import os
import sys

# Run all tests in the repository root.
notebook_path = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().get()
repo_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(notebook_path))
os.chdir(f'/Workspace/{repo_root}')
%pwd

# Skip writing pyc files on a readonly filesystem.
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

retcode = pytest.main([".", "-p", "no:cacheprovider"])

# Fail the cell execution if we have any test failures.
assert retcode == 0, 'The pytest invocation failed. See the log above for details.'
```